# FabricDnsService is not preferred DNS server on the node on solution with one stateful and one stateless

Tags: dns, azure-service-fabric

Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.FabricDnsService', Property='Environment', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
FabricDnsService is not preferred DNS server on the node.

Wondering if anyone has a place on where to start on getting this warning in azure fabric?

Comment: Looks like an open issue: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/496. I updated my local SDK to 6.0.232 -- the latest as of this writing -- but still seeing the issue.

Comment: So this error is coming up in a project where it is a stateless api that obtains information from a reliable dictionary in a stateful service and any api request gives a 500 error.Is this why?Why does the error happen?Is it down to my configuration of hardware/OS?

Answer (score 2):

Looks this was an issue on sf v6.0 and now it has beed fixed in v6.1

https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/496

For now to workaround this you should turn OFF all your network connections except one major, reset a local cluster, redeploy the app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-manifest